# Js - Capturing a 400 error event that appears in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension for Facebook that runs a script in the page.
Facebook in its normal operation sometimes shows the following message in the Chrome console (with red):

```
kZLAjcLHBWC.js:26 GET https://www.facebook.com/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/fetch/?limit=50&shown…=o&__req=9w&__be=-1&__pc=PHASED%3ADEFAULT&__rev=2661965&__srp_t=1478186873 400 ()
```

I want to create any js function that will determine when this event is happening (the 400 GET error).

Comment: You should specify where those errors come from. Your code? You should include it. Some third-party code? You need to explain that.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Ok, in order to make it more clear: I want to make simple function that captures this behaviour which shows in the console:

`kZLAjcLHBWC.js:26 GET https://www.facebook.com/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/fetch/?limit=50&shown…=o&__req=9w&__be=-1&__pc=PHASED%3ADEFAULT&__rev=2661965&__srp_t=1478186873 400 ()`

The 400 GET error is not caused by my script. I only want to capture it with my script.

Comment: What's the purpose of the (hypothetical) handler of this event? How is your code going to react?

Comment: The extension clicks on a button multiple times, up until Facebook starts sending only these error messages and stops the normal behaviour. At this point I want the extension to stop clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be challenging to catch from a content script; since it's not a JS error that bubbles up, it has to be caught in the page's own code, and [there are barriers to that](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). They can be overcome, but then you're operating in the possibly hostile environment of the page's code.

An alternative is to use [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest), specifically `chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred` event. This will allow you to detect errors on specific requests.

However, this can't be done from a content script. You'd need a background script that messages the content script when the event happens.